# Shadow Image don't scale twitter bootstrap

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, scale

My shadow image don't like to scale:

http://www.release.ipe-deutschland.de/index.php?article_id=9

[image]

If I scale the window browser:

[image]

Where is the bug?

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: in the `img` tag try putting `width="100%"`.

Comment: i don't use img tag the img was to use as background-image in the class size-shadow

Comment: Okay! So in the css where you have defined box-shadow, try using width:100%. Does it work?

Comment: If i change by the class .size-shadow width: 960px in width:100% so my images float left

Comment: Okay, so instead of using `width:<some absolute value>` try using `width:<some percentage>`. For example, I guess in your case 70% would work.

Comment: hey, sorry i see now that i don't set a link: http://www.release.ipe-deutschland.de/index.php?article_id=9 here is my link